# How to know which input method I am using on NixOS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, input-languages, input, nixos

I am using NixOS. This is my [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-nixos-config). As you see, I am using GNOME as the Desktop Environment.

I would like to find out which **input method** I am using. I can't find it.

In Ubuntu, people can find it like this:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1615718/169815815-5a3a8171-2a20-4335-92a6-b801cabee34e.png]

Since Ubuntu is also GNOME, I guess it is similar.

Is there some command on terminal that I could use to find this out?

Comment: Gnome's default IM is `ibus`, you can get/set it per-session using `gsettings` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262220/247007